# how complicated do hash functions need to be in order to be efficient?

Tags: c++, algorithm, hash

trying to make a good hash function for a 5x5 tic tac toe program this is what i came up with so far. my understanding of hash functions is that youre just trying to make a random function that kind of scatters possibilities (in this case board states) around to have some sort of equal distribution.

```
int hashfunc(char board[][5], int size)
{
  int row, col, Hash;

  int multiplier = 1;

  for(row = 0; row < 5; row++)
    {
      multiplier++;
      for (col = 0; col < 5; col++)
        {
          if (board[row][col] == 'X')
          {
            Hash += 3*multiplier;
          }
          else if (board[row][col] == 'O')
          {
            Hash += 4*multiplier*multiplier;
          }
          else if (board[row][col] == ' ')
          {
            Hash += 5*multiplier*multiplier*multiplier;
          }
        }
    }

  Hash %= size;


  return Hash;
}
```

any pointers would be appreciated

Comment: What is the hash *for*? Seems like the representation of the board is sufficient since there's no other distinguishing features included in the function.

Comment: @DaveNewton nothing specific just trying to practice hashing

Comment: There isn't going to be a good, hard rule on this. What makes a good hashing function good is going to depend a lot on the nature of the data being hashed. Sometimes it's going to be trivial and other times you'll have to jump through some pretty crazy hoops to keep collisions down to an acceptable level.

Comment: You can store a 5x5 board in an uint64_t using only the lower 50 bits where every tile takes 2 bits. That already enumerates the boards nicely. But you can do `board % prime` as hash function to get a smaller range of numbers at the risk of collisions. So the answer is: the hash function can be very simple.

Comment: What is the question here? Your title is very generic, yet you go into this specific case. Which are you interested in? Do you have a reason to think your current hash function is not "good"?

Comment: @JaMiT well im just wondering of the collisions that would be caused after doing modulus by table size, is this an over engineered function or what are some ways it can be better?

Comment: @yessir *"wondering of the collisions that would be caused after doing modulus by table size"* -- this is more of a concern than a reason. A reason would be more like you played a game, hashed the board at the end of each turn, and observed that there were more repeats than you'd like.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think hash need to be complicated, cryptographic hash function may be complicate but it has other reasons. OTOH, one may want to preserve locality of input values, then `x/N` may be a good candidate..

Answer (score 0):

Hash functions used for distributing items in a hash table are usually quite fast and not very complicated.

Polynomial hashes are the most common, often with some kind of step and the end to mix the high bits into the low ones.  That would look something like this:

```
hash=0
for char in string:
    hash = hash * SOME_ODD_PRIME + char
hash = hash ^ (hash>>16)
```

Of course there is the issue of picking the constant.

When in doubt, I usually use an [FNV hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fowler%E2%80%93Noll%E2%80%93Vo_hash_function), because someone went through the trouble of testing it in various scenarios.  I still add the mixing step.

In your case, that would look like this:

```
int hashfunc(char board[][5], int size)
{
  int row, col, hash;

  hash = (int)0x811c9dc5;

  for(row = 0; row < 5; row++) {
    for (col = 0; col < 5; col++) {
      hash = hash ^ (int)board[row][col];
      hash *= 0x01000193;
    }
  }
  hash &= 0x7FFFFFFF; // make sure it's positive
  hash ^= (hash >> 10); // mix high bits into low bits
  return hash % size;
}
```